# Google Cloud flexible environment JSON log format

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the documentation on logging for flexible environments, the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging) state:

> Custom log files must have the suffix `.log` or `.log.json`. If the suffix is `.log.json`, the logs must be in JSON format with one JSON object per line.

I couldn't find any further details on logging in a JSON format.

I'm interested in this format, because plain text logs are treated as 1 entry per line. The Google Cloud logging console doesn't seem to interpret those logs in any special way.

Is there a special JSON format to make the Google Cloud console treat those logs differently?

If so, what is this format and is there any documentation for this?